# Android RecyclerView does not work properly with data from retrofit request

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a screen with CardViews inside of a RecyclerView. The data for each card is retrieved from an ArrayList. As soon as I manually add data to the ArrayList, everything works fine. However, when data is added by an API using retrofit, cards are displayed only if at least one element is manually added to the ArrayList. In addition, if I switch to another menu and then return to a list of cards, only the manually added cards are displayed.

[List with cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAJaS.png)

[Only manually added card is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y01Uq.png)

[Full code](https://github.com/yevklym/Wechselkurs)

```
public class CurrencyRates extends Fragment {
ArrayList<CurrencyModel> currencyModelArrayList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currency_rates, container, false);
    currencyModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getRates("EUR", "USD");
    getRates("USD", "AUD");
    getRates("EUR", "GBP");
    getRates("EUR", "CNY");
    currencyModelArrayList.add(new CurrencyModel("EUR", "CZK", 24.8821));
    RecyclerView currencyRV;
    currencyRV = view.findViewById(R.id.RVCurrency);

    CurrencyAdapter currencyAdapter = new CurrencyAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), currencyModelArrayList);

    //cardview two columns
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 2);
    currencyRV.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    currencyRV.setAdapter(currencyAdapter);

    return view;
}

public void getRates(String baseCurrency, String exchangeCurrency) {

    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<JsonObject> call = retrofitInterface.getData(baseCurrency, exchangeCurrency);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            JsonObject res = response.body();
            JsonPrimitive rate = res.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("conversion_rate");
            currencyModelArrayList.add(new CurrencyModel(baseCurrency, exchangeCurrency, Double.parseDouble(rate.toString())));

        }

        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        }

    });
}}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class CurrencyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<CurrencyModel> currencyModelArrayList;

public CurrencyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CurrencyModel> currencyModelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.currencyModelArrayList = currencyModelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CurrencyModel model = currencyModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.baseCurrencyTV.setText(model.getBaseCurrency());
    holder.exchangeCurrencyTV.setText("/ " + model.getExchangeCurrency());
    holder.rateTV.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRate()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return currencyModelArrayList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView baseCurrencyTV, exchangeCurrencyTV, rateTV;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        baseCurrencyTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBaseCurrency);
        exchangeCurrencyTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVExchangeCurrency);
        rateTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVRate);
    }
}}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Navigation
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.currencyRates, R.id.converter).build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}}
```

Retrofit:

```
    public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static RetrofitClient instance;
    public static RetrofitInterface myRetrofitInterface;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(RetrofitInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
    public interface RetrofitInterface {

    String BASE_URL = "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/";

    @GET("v6/API_KEY/pair/{baseCurrency}/{exchangeCurrency}")
    Call<JsonObject> getData(@Path("baseCurrency") String baseCurrency,
                                @Path("exchangeCurrency") String exchangeCurrency);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add an item to the list you should notify the adapter

```
public void getRates(String baseCurrency, String         exchangeCurrency) {

 RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface =   RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterface.class);
Call<JsonObject> call = retrofitInterface.getData(baseCurrency, exchangeCurrency);

call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        JsonObject res = response.body();
        JsonPrimitive rate = res.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("conversion_rate");
        currencyModelArrayList.add(new CurrencyModel(baseCurrency, exchangeCurrency, Double.parseDouble(rate.toString())));           
        CurrencyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// add this line
    }      
  });
```

}}